# Subtracting a xts object from a subset of xts object

Tags: r, xts

```
con = gzcon(url('http://www.systematicportfolio.com/sit.gz', 'rb'))
source(con)
close(con)
load.packages("TTR,PerformanceAnalytics,quantmod,lattice")

#######################################################
#Get and Prep Data
#######################################################
data <- new.env()
tickers<-spl("VTI,IEF,TLT,DBC,VNQ,GLD")

getSymbols(tickers, src = 'yahoo', from = '1980-01-01', env = data)
for(i in ls(data)) data[[i]] = adjustOHLC(data[[i]], use.Adjusted=TRUE)

bt.prep(data, align='remove.na', dates='1990::2013')
```

I am experiencing the problem of subtracting a specific column from a xts object.

```
prices = data$prices
ret = prices / mlag(prices) - 1
ret - ret[,3]  #subtract column three from every other column don't seem to work
```

Is there a quick solution?

I tried:

```
apply(ret,2,function(x) x - x[,3]) #doesn't seem to work
```

Any ideas?

Comment: SIT uses XTS object to wrap time series, so I don't think that would be a problem. If you do str(ret), its an xts object.

Comment: SIT wraps time series with an XTS object. The above example just downloads the data and have SIT wrap it around an XTS object. But I will edit it now for a "minimal" version..

Comment: Here's something a little more `apply`-like: `sweep(x, 1, x[, 3])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Next time, please provide a *minimal* reproducible example.  For example:

```
> library(xts)
> data(sample_matrix)
> x <- as.xts(sample_matrix)
> x-x[,1]
Error in `-.default`(x, x[, 1]) : non-conformable arrays
> apply(x, 2, function(y) y-x[,1])
Error in array(ans, c(len.a%/%d2, d.ans), if (!all(vapply(dn.ans, is.null,  : 
  length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent
```

The problem is that xts objects have a `dim` attribute by default and it isn't dropped when subsetting like it is with matrix and zoo class objects.  You can force dropping it by setting `drop=TRUE` in your subsetting call.

```
> head(x-x[,1,drop=TRUE])
           Open       High         Low       Close
2007-01-02    0 0.07799532 -0.08936727  0.07799532
2007-01-03    0 0.19137980  0.00000000  0.16717014
2007-01-04    0 0.00000000 -0.15681864 -0.08859811
2007-01-05    0 0.00000000 -0.15243423 -0.03887316
2007-01-06    0 0.00000000 -0.13311797 -0.06320448
2007-01-07    0 0.08349916 -0.14025780 -0.14025780
```

This works because `x[,1,drop=TRUE]` returns a "vector xts" (i.e. a dimensionless xts object) and the vector is recycled along `x` during the `-` call.